# Why I cannot save IDNA encoded URL into varchar column of SQL Server

Tags: unicode, sql-server-2012, ascii, idn

I have IDN URL like this :
http://президент.рф/
which is represented with IDN URL http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai/
When I try to save that URL into varchar column of SQL server I am getting ??????.
Isn't IDN Punycode should be ASCII representation of Unicode characters ?

Comment: `declare @t table(url varchar(50));insert into @t values ('http://xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai/ ');select * from @t` works fine. It won't automatically convert `http://президент.рф/` if that's what you were expecting.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for observation. I have some kind of bug in my ado.net code. I will need to investigate.